# Error on trying to execute recursive command on CMD Windows 10

Tags: bash, shell, imagemin

I'm trying to use a recursive command to minify images on my project, but when i execute the command, it give this error:

"The parameter command is still specified"

The command is:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec imagemin {}/* --out-dir={}/* \;
```

What is wrong with this? I'm using Windows 10.

Thank you

Comment: Try without the final back slash before the semicolon?  If that doesn't work, please post your configuration - the find command you're using is a linux command, which you could be using with Windows Subsystem for Linux, or with cygwin, or other tools.

Comment: Same error :/ i'm using the Linux subsystem

Comment: What actual command do you want to execute for each file? Currently for a file `./relative/path/to/foo.jpg` you would be executing `imagemin ./relative/path/to/foo.jpg/* --out-dir=./relative/path/to/foo.jpg/*`, is this what you expect?